# Post values to cakePHP controller action and display it

Tags: cakephp, facebook-graph-api, jquery

I am using Facebook Javascript API for Facebook authentication and implementing other Facebook features, in a cake PHP based site. Now I am using API for fetching the Facebook friends and I need to do some operations with the friends list. So I am posting the  JSON object array to the corresponding controller action. Later on this page is loaded using another AJAX call . In between I am loosing the posted data. What I need is, I need to compare frien's list with existing Facebook IDs. I am using the below code

```
   FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: baseUrl+'/user_details/userlist',
        data: response,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {

        }});
    });
```

How can I achieve this ? or I need to use PHP based SDK  ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `data` option to this format:

```
data: { "data" : response },
```

Then check `$this->request->data` on your Cake controller (assuming Cake 2.x).

Comment: actually the issue is not with the parameters. It is some issue with the calling. Because I can see the output in Firebug console but it is showing nothing on the browser window. I am calling the page from another AJAX call and I think it is outputting a fresh page which don't have the posted value. Also I am not storing the alue anywhere. By the way I am using cake 1.3

Comment: But what do you want the browser window to show? Your code doesn't tell the browser to show anything. The response from the inner ajax call will be available on the success handler: `success: function(response) { console.log(response) }`.

Comment: is there anyway that I can process the list that is submitted in controller and display the result.?

Comment: You have to display the results from inside the `success` callback, it will be passed to the function as I mentioned in the comment above.